# Why can't objects of type void be created in C++?

Tags: c++, types, void

C++ doesn't allow creating objects of type `void`. Why is that?

Comment: Obligatory space-time physics joke goes here.

Comment: well, do you know what is "void"? That is "nothing", how can you create nothing? Just kidding.

Comment: @Shuo: it's a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the code below.

```
class Foo
{
    // etc ...
};

int main()
{
    // Declaring an object...
    Foo foo;
    // foo has been created.

    // etc ...

    return 0; // When function returns, foo will be destroyed.
}
```

In order to know how to actually create the object, the compiler has to know the type. Informally, you can think of `void` as a "type" representing an absence of type. Therefore, the compiler can't possibly know how to create a `void` object. You can't create an object you don't know how to create.

```
int main()
{
    void v; // "I don't know how to create this!"
}
```

That being said, there are other cases where `void` makes sense. For example, a `void` function has no return value. You can't assign a type to things (like return values) that do not exist.

You can also have a pointer to `void`, or `void*`. Unlike the plain `void`, `void*` is valid and simply means "*a pointer to an object of some unknown type*". Obviously you can't do much with a `void*` until you cast it into an actual, known type (assuming the cast is safe, of course).

Comment: That's conceptually true, but not accurate in regards to the specification.  `void` is certainly a type, it is simply an incomplete type that represents an empty set of values.

Comment: I’m not happy with this description. The same is absolutely true for built-types such as `int`: it doesn’t have constructors nor destructors and yet the compiler happily allows creating objects of it. In summary, this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I have always thought built in types had constructors that is why I can do "int x(4)".

Comment: @MeThinks They support constructor-like syntax but they don’t have constructors, only initialisers.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks very much for that. So in this case if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck; then its very duck like but not necessarily a duck. Just seen the standard say constructors(member functions) have to be defined in a class and built in types are not classes. So just syntactic sugar after all :)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I was trying to explain in somewhat familiar terms why you can't create `void` objects, but apparently I've failed with respect to that. I've removed any mention of constructors and destructors.

Comment: Thanks. It was so nice of you to answer me.

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain much. It is meaningful to have a void return value, which means no return value. Why isn't it meaningful to instantiate void, meaning nothing is instantiated? Why can't I type `void v; return v;`? Sure, it might not sound useful on its own, but it could be useful in eg. a template.

Answer (score 12):

It is because `void` is an incomplete type.

From Standard docs., incomplete types *3.9* states that,

> `5` A class that has been declared but not defined, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an
>   incompletely-defined object type.38) Incompletely-defined object types and **the void types are incomplete types** (3.9.1).
>   Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.
>
> 38) **The size and layout of an instance of an incompletely-defined object type is unknown.**

Since `void` is an incomplete type, it's size and layout cannot be determined and hence it cannot be defined.

Answer (score 4):

As a side note, you **can** create a temporary of type `void`:

```
void f()
{
    return void();
}

void g()
{
    return cout << "hi", f();
}
```

this is valid code. It is extremely useful in generic code. It was even considered to allow the usage of built in types (including void) in some places like base classes:

```
template<class T> class A : T { };

A<string> x; // works
A<int> y; // error, but could be usefull
A<void> z; // error, but could be usefull.
```

Comment: Is this really a temporary in standard parlance? Then the standard would contain a contradiction: an object in C++ is defined as a memory location of size != 0 so the above *cannot* be an object.

Comment: There is no temporary void object in `return cout << "hi", f();`. This expression means "call operator << on cout and "hi", discard its result, then call f() and return its result". So basically, it all comes down to `void foo() {} void bar() { return foo(); }` - this works, but there is never any temporary object, never anything returned at all.

Comment: I don't think it is a temporary. I think it takes advantage of a bunch of special-case exceptions in the standard. (1) a void function can use `return` with a void expression, (2) `void()` is a void expression, *not* a constructor call for an incomplete type as you'd think just by looking at it. The intention of those exceptions is to make it *look* as though a "void object" is returned, though. As ybungalobill says it helps write generics. But try taking a `const` reference to that thing that appears to be a temporary, see how far you get (8.2.3/4) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`void` is a placeholder indicating **no object of any type** is expected.

#### As a function argument specification

Historically C used an empty argument list in a function declaration ala `return_type f();` to allow `f()` to be called with however-many and whatever-type arguments were specified at each call site, whereas `return_type f(void);` made it explicit no arguments were expected or allowed.  I.e. C was prepared to trust the programmer to get the number and types of arguments right, with any mistake likely to corrupt data and/or crash the program.

#### As a function return type

There woud also be some ambiguities in the language if `void` wasn't there to establish the overall "type variable|function" sequence that's part of the grammar of the language.  For example:

```
f();  // declaration of a function that returns nothing?
      // OR a function call?
```

#### Comparison with other types

It is not really a data type itself in the sense of representing some interpretation of an area of memory, as int, float, char etc., classes, unions etc. all do.

#### pointers to void

For `void*`, it indicates a loss of insight into the contents of memory at the contained address, such that sometime before dereferencing the pointer it must be cast to a specific type reflecting the bitwise layout of data at that memory address.  Then, the compiler can interpret and operate on that bit layout in accord with the then-known data type.

Answer (score 2):

In `C++`, every thing can be related to object. So, when said -

```
void variable ;
```

How many bytes must the platform allocate for `variable` with out knowing it's type. Is it `int` or `float` or `double` or any other primitive type. So, it is not allowed.

Comment: Though that is only something that B.S. forgot to define (or did not define purposely because he thougth it was useless, who knows). There is no urgent reason why it has to be that way. For example gcc has sizeof(void) == 1. It does warn about it with warnings enabled, but it works just fine. Of course reason why this exists is not that someone would actually want to use it, it exists merely to keep consistency because arithmetic on void pointers is defined, and the gcc guys felt that if you can increment a pointer type, you must be able to query its value's size too.

Comment: As a funny anectode, for similar reasons ("to make pointers and taking addresses work"), the size of an empty struct is 1.

Comment: This answer is false. There is no requirement for the compiler to allocate any bytes at all when you instantiate a type. This allows it to eg. keep variables in registers, or optimize them out entirely. It only needs to put the variable in memory if you try taking its address.

Answer (score 1):

void represents Nothing.Even you are creating function with Void type we no need to return a value.Same like Here also No object of type void is declared.

Answer (score 1):

It is, simply, an arbitrary decision, from C.

In C, all types (except from `void`) are used to carry a value. `void`, by definition, does not hold any value. The language designers therefore decided it would not be possible to instantiate it.

C++ takes after C, and the decision remained. Otherwise it would have been necessary to define a storage size (probably the same as `bool`).

In C++ it is indeed annoying, especially because of the special casing necessary for template classes / functions, but no-one deemed it worthy of modification since it's possible to specialize the templates for `void` and thus it's not blocking.